# Colocar condicionante en reporte RDL - Visual 2012, SQL Server

Tags: sql, visual-studio, vb.net, reportviewer, visual

Quiero colocar una condicionante en un diseño RDL que estoy haciendo, a partir de un query

este es el query

```
SELECT 
Nombre,
Cuenta,
Monto,
TipoOperacion
FROM Transacciones
```

Este es el resultado que me arroja

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el diseño RDL quiero que solamente me tire por ejemplo los registros que tengan C en el campo TipoOperacion, lo quiero hacer desde el RDL no desde el query, ya que despues agregare otro cuadro RDL donde me muestre solo las que tengan D en el campo TipoOperacion

El tema es que no se que funcion usar para ello en el RDL, estaba usando esta

```
=IIF(Fields!TipoOperacion.Value="C",Fields!Monto.Value,"")
```

Pero igual me muestra todas incluyendo las que son D

Ayuda porfavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vas a tu diseño del reporte y das clic derecho sobre la fila de detalles del **Tablix** y seleccionas la **opción** **Row Visibility...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la próxima ventana que sale marcas la tercera opción, **Show or hide based on an expression**, y das clic sobre el botón de al lado (**Fx**).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta nueva ventana que se abre pones la condición de visibilidad de tu fila:

```
=Fields!TipoOperacion.Value = "C"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma ocultamos todas las filas donde el **campo TipoOperacion** sea igual a **"C"**.